# Is there a simpler way to create a hash of model data? (Ruby beginner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
   list = []
    Merchant.all.each do |merchant|
      if merchant.url.present? && merchant.url != merchant.api_data.url
        list.push({
          :id => merchant.id,
          :name => merchant.name,
          :another => merchant.another,
          :another => merchant.another,
          :another => merchant.another
        })
      end
    end
```

Is there is simpler way to create a hash of only some of the fields of that object? Sorry if this is too obvious. I'm transitioning over to Ruby from PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
merchants = Merchant.all.map do |merchant|
  if merchant.url.present? && merchant.url != merchant.api_data.url
    merchant.attributes.slice("id", "name", "another")
  end
end.compact
```

Notes:

- Why do you need to extract attributes from a merchant instance instead of using the record itself?
- Don't use generic names as `list`. Give meaningful names to variables.
- Consider moving some logic to the SQL level. That's it, create scopes that filter the records you want, it will much faster.

Using records:

```
merchants = Merchant.all.select do |merchant|
  merchant.url.present? && merchant.url != merchant.api_data.url
end
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I need to extract a few fields to send that data as an email.

Comment: no need to build a hash for that, just pass the merchant objects around and access the attributes when appropriate.

Comment: So like this?...  `list = []
        Merchant.all.each do |merchant|
          if merchant.url.present? && merchant.url != merchant.api_data.url
            list.push(merchant)
          end
        end`

Comment: well, in this case use select. In Ruby each is much less used, we have map/select/reject/inject/..., functional programming stuff.

Comment: That's amazing! I hadn't seen that in rails before. Incredible!

Comment: Remember, to get the most out of Rails, you need to learn basic Ruby. Pay particular attention to the functional methods on Array, Hash, and Enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

You could `#reject` or `#select` all the unwanted/needed attributes from `merchant.attributes` so they do or do not get added to your list. Might have a look at the [reject method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Hash.html#method-i-reject). Though it's not uncommon to just add the attributes the way you already do.

Best regards

Tobias